# TFS 2012 Add custom Dictionary

Tags: tfs, custom-fields

We're about to implement TFS 2012 and I've been having some fun customizing some work items to aid us in our reporting. One issue we have is our reporting based on clients.

Our Product Backlog Items keep our requirements, however, we need to report our requirements per client (government regulations).  Some requirements will affect all clients, some will only reflect certain ones.  I've been able to add a global list of clients along with a multi-select option and that part is working great.

The issue is we need to also note the requirement number for each selected client.  I know I can go in and add a field for each 'Client Requirement', but as that list gets bigger, that screen will be insanely huge.

Does anybody know of such a way to implement something of the sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to create a custom Work Item Type for Clients.  Then link your PBI's to the appropriate client WI's.  When you create a link you can enter a link comment also which you could use to capture the client-specific requirement number.

Comment: I did exactly this...a new ItemType that is a simple Key Value pair that I can Link multiple to each item.  Simple for now.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom "Client Requirement" work item that has the list of clients to select and includes a field for Client ID. You can then either use the related link type or create your own, maybe "Implements \ Implemented By" so that you can create a Reporting Services report that pulls the ID's